# Dynamically adding Input form field issue reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add one cascaded form(inner) field dynamically on click of a button **+Add Content**. The array for the field is getting updated but the view is still same.

However, when I try to add the outer field on click of a button **+Add Heading** dynamically its getting added with no issues.
Below is the stackblitz url for reference. Thanks in advance.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-utjwsu?embed=1&file=index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only ever rendering one Content field, and the `{this.AddContentInput}` isn't valid syntax. You can edit the AddContentBox method to render all of the Content fields:

Original:

```
...
<FormGroup>
    <Label className="set-label-pos upload-img" for="Heading">Content</Label>
    <input className="form-control" type="text"/>
</FormGroup>
{this.AddContentInput}
...
```

Replaced with:

```
...
{ this.AddContentFields(element) }
...
```

and

```
AddContentFields(element) {
  return element.Content.map(content => {
    return (
      <FormGroup>
        <Label className="set-label-pos upload-img" for="Heading">Content</Label>
          <input className="form-control" type="text"/>
        </FormGroup>
    );
  })
}
```

Here's an edited version of the app with my changes: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lcy2te

Comment: Thank you all for your timely help. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine and the state is updating perfectly. The problem is that the `Content` part is added only once in your code. I just used a function which you already added in it

`{this.addContentTextBox(element.Content)}`

Just replace the `AddContentBox` function with this:

```js
AddContentBox(){
        return this.state.content.map((element,i)=>(
            <div className="header-content" key={i} >
                <div className="heading-content-wrapper">
                <FormGroup>
                <Label className="set-label-pos upload-img" for="Heading">Heading</Label>
                <input className="form-control" type="text"/>
                </FormGroup>
                {this.addContentTextBox(element.Content)}
                {this.AddContentInput}
                <FormGroup>
                <Button color="success" onClick={this.AddContentInput.bind(this,i)}>+ Add Content</Button>
                </FormGroup>
            </div>
            </div>
        ))
    }
```

You have the code in that file, but i think you forgot to add it in the function.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the content variable. In your function `AddContentBox()` you are using `this.state.content.map(...)`

`this.state.content` is an array of object like `{Heading: '', Content: [{value: ''}]}`

**BUT** in your function `AddContentInput()` your are pushing an object inside an object of this array `contents[index].Content.push({value:''})`

Depending on your needs you should either push in the root array `contents.push({Heading: '', Content: [{value: ''}]}` *OR* iterate the right array in your function `AddContentBox()` and use `this.state.content[0].Content.map(...)`